# Interpreter creates copy of object in the trace

Tags: c++, copy, tcl, trace

[Tcl: Interpreter creates copy of traced object whet it goes changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764691/tcl-interpreter-creates-copy-of-traced-object-whet-it-goes-changed) in this question I asked why does interpreter creates a copy of object in the trace? I understand that using handles is the right way here but it requires huge work, therefore I need workaround solution.

I need the code in the trace behave exactly the same as if it was written after set command. **I need to change the object in the trace** and I want the interpreter not to make a copy of object. It would be great if somehow disable the copying functionality in the trace function.

I have looked here http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/TraceVar.3.html but didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## DON'T DO THIS!

---

Changing the `Tcl_Obj` itself when there are multiple references held open to it (i.e., when `Tcl_IsShared` reports that the value is shared) can cause all sorts of semantic problems (many functions — e.g., `Tcl_SetIntObj` — specifically check and will abort the process if you try) so you need to be exceptionally careful. You're moving outside Tcl's semantics; there are dragons here!

To directly modify a `Tcl_Obj`, look at the `bytes` field of the structure (the `length` field is supposed to be kept as the `strlen` of `bytes`). That's writable; just change it, bearing in mind that it is always encoded as pseudo-UTF-8 (which is very straight forward for ASCII characters other than `\u0000`). If you want to change what is allocated, that field *must* be allocated with `Tcl_Alloc`. If `bytes` is `NULL`, there is no string representation; look to the internal representation for meaning.

The internal representation of a `Tcl_Obj` is determined by the `internalRep` union and the `typePtr` field. Understanding the meaning of the `internalRep` depends on understanding what `typePtr` points to; usually, if you didn't implement it, you shouldn't poke around at all. We *do* change what internal representations are present in patch releases sometimes. If you defined the `typePtr` to point to a structure you own, you'll know how to understand the internal representation. When the `typePtr` field is `NULL`, there is no internal representation.

Sometimes you may encounter a `Tcl_Obj` with neither internal nor string representation. DO NOT CHANGE THIS if you find one. It is reserved for the (very highly-shared) empty value.

While is technically possible to alter a shared object by poking around inside, *the rest of Tcl assumes that you're not going to do this* so it's pretty random what might break. You might even get away with it! But be aware that we won't formally support you; you're on your own.